# Multi-colored Grid

Tags: java, grid

my assignment is make a gaming generator for 3 different types of puzzle game. i just have to finish up the last game which is Bejeweled. i have made the grid already using the GridLayout filled with buttons.

i just need to apply 7 different colors on all the buttons. ive tried using this code before:

```
String[] backgroundColors = {"CYAN","PINK","YELLOW"};  
int number = (int)(Math.random() * 3);  
String c = (backgroundColors[number]);
```

(then after i add the button to the pane i dd this:)

```
buttonBejeweled.setBackgroundColor(c);
```

and it failed.
i thought maybe i should use and array but ive searched and haven't found any unfortunately.
Please help me out with a random color generator, by use of arrays preferably.

Comment: A Button in Java does not have a method `setBackgroundColor` but a `.setBackground(Color c)` I'd recommend you look for documentation about the Color class in Java.

Comment: +1 setBackgroundColor() is used on Views in Android. Swing components just have the setBackground() method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does the .setBackgroundColor() use a String parameter? If it doesn't work I'm guessing that it uses a parameter of type Color. Have you imported the color library? If not, to access colors you have to use the Color class and access colors using Color.CYAN for example, and so you would do

```
Color[] backgroundColors = {Color.CYAN,Color.PINK,Color.YELLOW};  
int number = (int)(Math.random() * 3);  
Color c = (backgroundColors[number]); 
buttonBejeweled.setBackgroundColor(c);
```

Comment: this method worked perfectly. thank. only issue now is that the colors are generated randomly, but not individually. meaning if the color was yellow, then they are all yellow. do you have any idea of how to fix this this?

Comment: If you want each button to be a separate color, what I would do is create an array of the buttons you want to use, and to each button in a loop just recycle the random number, color assignment, and the 'buttonBejewled' would become 'ButtonArray.get(i).setBackgroundColor(c)' so instead of just doing the function once, you have to assign a color to each button each time you want a new button color. Try that.

Answer (score 1):

You can use

```
Color[] backgroundColors = {Color.RED,Color.GREEN,Color.BLUE};  
int number = (int)(Math.random() * 3);  
Color c = (backgroundColors[number]);
```

Comment: this is my error message using BlueJ: cannot find symbol - method setBackgroundColor(java.awt.Color)

Comment: i've imported the necessary packages, im just wondering why it's not executing the background color for a single button.